# Where is my code going wrong in creating this matrix?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Consider the n simultaneous equations Ax=b, where
>
> A_(ij) = (i+j)^2 and b_i = sum(A_ij) from j=0 to n, with i=0,1,...,n, j=0,1,...,n.
>
> Write an program that solves these equations for any given n.

So I am supposed to create the matrix A and the vector b, and then use these to solve Ax=b. I am fine with creating A, and it is done using the following code:

```
A = numpy.zeros(n*n).reshape(n,n)
def matrix(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            A[i,j] = (i+j)**2

matrix(n)
print A
```

For any chosen n, this gives me a nice looking nxn matrix. However, I am now struggling to create the vector b. This is my code so far:

```
b = numpy.zeros(n*1).reshape(n,1)
def sumRow(n):
    while i = 0:
        for j in range(0,n):
            b[i] = math.fsum(A[i,j])
sumRow(n)
print b
```

First things first, I don't know how to then do it from i=0 up to i=n.

I am also getting errors when running this code which I am struggling to solve.

My thought process is as follows:

1. I create an nx1 vector of zeros.
2. I then define a function in n which I name sumRow.
3. Then I tell the function to do what the formula for b says.
4. For row zero and for j in the range zero to n, I tell the computer to make the ith row of b the sum of all of the numbers in the ith row of A.

Can someone help me to modify this second block of code in order to obtain a matrix b for a given n.

Comment: "I don't know how to then do it from i=0 up to i=n" - why don't you use the same pattern as before (range...)?

Comment: You should probably `return A` and `return b` and assign those values `b = sumRow(n)` and `A = matrix(n)`

Comment: `i = 0` is an assignment. You set i to 0. But I guess you wanted to compare `i == 0`?

Comment: And finally: have a look what [`fsum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html). Currently, you build a sum of a single element. You want `b[i] += A[i,j]` I guess.

Comment: If there are n sim. eqn. then i and j would run from 1 to n, (or 0 to n-1), but the definition of b seems to define n+1 equations. Also, the answer to the question is probably slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem of populating vector `b`-

```
b = numpy.zeros(n*1).reshape(n,1)
def sumRow(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        b[i] = math.fsum(A[i]) //calculates the sum of all elements of the given row
sumRow(n)
print b
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, and actually I'm quite disappointed I didn't get that myself!

Comment: You are welcome. Consider reading the documentation properly before implementing a function,

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get `b` using list comprehension

```
b = [sum(x) for x in A]
```